# Cant access values in object after api request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to index to the object. You can see below it shows the object, but when I console out `myThumbs` or when I try to index something in the object it says `undefined`.

```
thumbHelper(){
  let myThumbs = {};
  this.state.apiResponse.fileNames.forEach(f=>{
    this.getThumb(f).then(blob=>{
      myThumbs[f] = blob;
    });
  });
  this.setState({myThumbs});
  console.log(myThumbs);
  console.log(myThumbs["134711.jpg"])
  console.log(this.state.myThumbs);
}
```

[image: Console Output]

React Dev Tools State

[image]

Comment: as u can see it shows the object wehn i console out myThumbs but when i try to index something it says undefined

Comment: try using callback function `this.setState({myThumbs}, () =>  console.log(myThumbs["134711.jpg"]));`

Comment: I wrote en example here:

async thumbHelper() {
  const fileNames = this.state.apiResponse.fileNames;

  let myThumbs = {};

  const promises = fileNames.forEach((name) => {
    promises.push(this.getThumb(name));
  });

  const data = await Promise.all(promises);

  fileNames.forEach((name, index) => {
    myThumbs[name] = data[index];
  })

  this.setState({ myThumbs });
}

Comment: this doesnt work